# Java app running on Intel Edison can't read from sensor (and Python can)

Tags: java, iot, intel-edison

I created a [quick & dirty prototype in Python](https://github.com/alexwoolford/htu21d_logger/blob/master/htu21d_logger_python/htu21d_demo.py) that reads temperature/humidity from an [HTU21D sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13763) sensor that's connected to an Intel Edison. I'm trying to rewrite the Python prototype in Java. Unfortunately, the values being returned for temperature/humidity in Java are zero.

The code is posted on Github: https://github.com/alexwoolford/htu21d_logger. Under the covers, both Python and Java versions are using [upm](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/upm/java/index.html)/[mraa](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa).

Here's the Java code to read from the sensor:

```
upm_htu21d.HTU21D sensor = new upm_htu21d.HTU21D(1);
logger.info("Temperature: " + sensor.getTemperature() + "; humidity: " + sensor.getHumidity());
```

In the [Java example code](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/upm/java/classupm__htu21d_1_1_h_t_u21_d.html) for the sensor, the bus argument that's passed to the `upm_htu21d.HTU21D(0)` is zero.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Try to avoid *libmraa* crap as much as possible. The driver for your sensor is in kernel already, just enable it. (Yes, it would require some C code for now, you may find examples for other drivers under *arch/x86/platform/intel-mid/device_libs*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTU21D Java example code](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm/blob/master/examples/java/HTU21DSample.java) was missing the following call:

```
sensor.sampleData()
```

Thanks to [Jon Trulson](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jontrulson/) for identifying the [root cause](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm/issues/559).